# Count the number of file created after a specific datetime on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Wondering if there a way to list, especially count the number of files created after a specific date on a specific bucket on on Cloud Storage using gsutil?

Normal count is gsutil du gs://pub | wc -l but what about only objects created between 2023-01-01 00:00 and 03-01-2023 05:00 ?

Comment: It's not possible. That's why I wrote that article that will help you to achieve what you want: https://medium.com/google-cloud/extend-cloud-storage-filtering-with-bigquery-object-table-7ce4a0f75a3d